# weight sensor in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to create a weight sensor in gazebo simulation?. I need sense a weigth in the robot payload.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80886/weight-sensor-in-gazebo?/) by [DruizH](https://answers.ros.org/users/6881/druizh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably better to ask this at http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0